# How to get a motorbike to ride from Yogyakarta to Bangkok?

Tags: indonesia, motorcycles, bangkok, one-way

I am planning to ride through Indonesia by motorbike and want to end my trip in Bangkok.
Do you know of way to rent myself an enduro bike in [Yogyarka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogyakarta) or thereabouts, and leave it in [Bangkok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangkok)?

if not, buying one and trying to sell it after the trip seems to be the only option.

can you help me figure out what topics might be of importance to sell that indonesian imported motorbike in thailand?

thx in advance

edit: clarification

Comment: Yogya is a common abbreviation for Yogyakarta, Java, Indonesia.

Comment: @pnuts Then edit the question instead of snarking in the comments...

Comment: To sell the motorcycle in Bangkok, you will need to go through the import process, paying duties and getting the motorcycle registered in Thailand.  You also need to deal with temporary importation rules (or get a vehicle passport) to transit through Malaysia and/or Singapore.

Comment: @pnuts - The OP won't find a one way rental across countries like that, so buy-ride-sell is pretty much the only travel option.  But the question seems pretty straight forward to me, not sure why the "don't understand" police descended on it.

Comment: my further research confirmed there are only a few international motorbike rental companies and none that i found have offices in Indonesia.

Comment: @Tom - thx for having my back and the first ideas about what to pay attention to for importing the bike

Comment: @pnuts - The spare parts routine works as an import dodge (ie send it in in pieces, then reassemble upon arrival), but since he will drive the bike in as a working motorcycle, it will be kind of hard to claim it is only spare parts later.

Comment: @pnuts - Thailand doesn't impose duty, rather they record your entry, give you 30 days to ride around and ask where you are exiting (which border crossing).  The only way to leave without the motorcycle is by legally transferring ownership of it.

Answer (score 1):

Even for a trip inside Indonesia, it is usually easier to buy a second hand motorbike, then sell it when your trip is over

I never did it myself, but it my Indonesian friends told me it is the best way

Answer (score 0):

I got my hands on a link for second hand trading in Indonesia:

https://www.olx.co.id